# Schema Privileges does not display in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, user-interface, workbench

So I was trying to create a user and password for a particular database in Mysql Workbench, but the Schema Privileges does not seem to display completely for me to work on. Any reasons as to why?

[image: Schema Privileges]

Comment: The "quality" of Workbench makes me wonder whether Microsoft has planted a saboteur on its dev team.  Bugs are suspiciously numerous.  Have you verified that you're running the latest version?  Once upon a time, there was [Bug #69175](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68175) that broke things related to this screen if there was an underscore in the schema name.  I'm not saying this is that, but it seems suspiciously similar, with the `_` in your schema name.  Do you have this issue on other schemas with/without underscores in the name?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot As you said, I did have an "_" in my schema name. But the problem still remains after I removed it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the `_` is perfectly valid.  I was taking a stab in the dark based on the other bug report.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  should I re-install it again?

Comment: Reinstalling mysql *server* is essentially never needed, as most issues are better fixed through troubleshooting from the error log... but reinstalling *workbench*... maybe.  I'd try a fresh install on a different machine, first.

Comment: Just did a reinstall of Workbench 6.3.9 (on a Win 8.1) and the problem remains.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem only in version 6.3.9, on a Win 8.1 x64. Uninstalling 6.3.9, and installed 6.3.8, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85407) (glitch), and already reported to MySql team. I had the same problem, by the time it get fixed; Please use it by "restore down" window mode.

> When defining a user the "Schema Privileges" tab is non-functional when the Workbench window is in fullscreen mode (which is the default mode on start-up).  Only the "Schema" column is shown in the embedded window and the "revoke all privileges", "delete entry", and "add entry" buttons are missing.

**The problem goes away when the "restore down" window button is clicked and does NOT re-appear when the Workbench window is returned to fullscreen.**

**Glitch**
[image: with glitch]
**Without Glitch**
[image: without glitch]

Comment: This Resolved the issue for me...found it on my own as I didn't see your response until I came back to post my solution and found yours at the bottom with no votes.

Comment: This restore down button does not seems to be working anymore. Does this have any other workaround for window10 server?

Answer (score 2):

So on the Mac, and this may be different on Windows, the devs have gone minimalist with the interface in Workbench. So there are hidden controls where you have to move your mouse around until the cursor changes, only then can you see the control. Here you can see that the Schema Privileges section on the Mac doesn't show *at all* until you drag it up. Likely in Windows you would need to drag that right side to the right to increase the viewing area.

### Here they are collapsed:

[image: Schema Privileges collapsed on Mac OS X]

### When I drag up on the hidden control they show up again:

[image: Expanded controls]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution :

In C:\Users[you]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\cache, delete the **XXX.columns_widths** file where XXX is your connection name.

J-Luc

Comment: i deleted the file, but without any effect on the situation

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after my Windows 10 crashed due to a power outage during a Windows update.  Win10 basically installed a fresh copy of itself but kept my user directory, which included my original %AppData% settings from mysql.   I basically blew away the entire contents of C:\Users{my user name}\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench ... after which things started working properly again.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing `AppData` didn't work for me. It was bugging me on Windows 10 Workbench 6.3.x.

Solution was to uninstall it and re-install 6.2.5, by clicking "Previous GA version" from download page. It was back to the old, black Home screen, my connections were still there from 6.3.x and the UI glitch is gone.